Problem with converting object Rabbitmq in Java Spring
I am trying to integrate Rabbitmq streams into my java spring application. The problem is with conversion of the object of my custom class on the listener:

@Component
public class Runner implements CommandLineRunner {

    private final RabbitStreamTemplate rabbitStreamTemplate;
    
    public Runner(RabbitStreamTemplate rabbitStreamTemplate) {
        this.rabbitStreamTemplate = rabbitStreamTemplate;
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Sending message");
    
        UserMessage um = new UserMessage("John", "Smith");
    
         rabbitStreamTemplate.convertAndSend(um);
    
        System.out.println("Hello from my command line runner");
    }

}

package com.ts.travelSensei.rabbitmq;

import com.rabbitmq.stream.Environment;
import com.rabbitmq.stream.Message;
import com.rabbitmq.stream.MessageHandler;
import com.rabbitmq.stream.OffsetSpecification;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListener;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.RabbitListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.Jackson2JsonMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.rabbit.stream.config.StreamRabbitListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.rabbit.stream.listener.StreamListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.rabbit.stream.producer.RabbitStreamTemplate;
import org.springframework.rabbit.stream.support.StreamAdmin;
import org.springframework.rabbit.stream.support.converter.StreamMessageConverter;

import java.time.Duration;

@Configuration
public class RabbitMQConfig {

    @Bean
    StreamAdmin streamAdmin(Environment env) {
        return new StreamAdmin(env, sc -> {
            sc.stream("stream.queue1").maxAge(Duration.ofHours(2)).create();
        });
    }
    
    @Bean
    RabbitStreamTemplate streamTemplate(Environment env, MessageConverter messageConverter) {
        RabbitStreamTemplate template = new RabbitStreamTemplate(env, "stream.queue1");
        template.setProducerCustomizer((name, builder) -> builder.name("test"));
        template.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);
        return template;
    }
    
    @Bean
    RabbitListenerContainerFactory<StreamListenerContainer> rabbitListenerContainerFactory(Environment env) {
        return new StreamRabbitListenerContainerFactory(env);
    }
    
    @RabbitListener(queues = "stream.queue1")
    void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println("the message is received : " + in);
    }
    
    @RabbitListener(queues = "stream.queue1")
    void anotherListen(UserMessage in) {
        System.out.println("the message is received 2 : " + in.toString());
    }
    
    
    @Bean
    RabbitListenerContainerFactory<StreamListenerContainer> nativeFactory(Environment env) {
        StreamRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new StreamRabbitListenerContainerFactory(env);
        factory.setConsumerCustomizer((id, builder) -> {
            builder.name("myConsumer")
                    .offset(OffsetSpecification.first())
                    .autoTrackingStrategy();
        });
        return factory;
    }
    
    @Bean
    MessageConverter jackson2MessageConverter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }

}

package com.ts.travelSensei.rabbitmq;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.io.Serializable;

@Setter
@Getter
public class UserMessage implements Serializable {

    private String name;
    
    private String surname;
    
    public UserMessage(String name, String surname) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }

}

And here is the error I get:
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [[B] to [com.ts.travelSensei.rabbitmq.UserMessage] for GenericMessage [payload=byte[33], headers={amqp_expiration=0, amqp_contentEncoding=UTF-8, id=f6bacd4d-1160-fc81-6114-64767eb651ac, amqp_lastInBatch=false, contentType=application/json, __TypeId__=com.ts.travelSensei.rabbitmq.UserMessage, timestamp=1729684342210}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[33], headers={amqp_expiration=0, amqp_contentEncoding=UTF-8, id=f6bacd4d-1160-fc81-6114-64767eb651ac, amqp_lastInBatch=false, contentType=application/json, __TypeId__=com.ts.travelSensei.rabbitmq.UserMessage, timestamp=1729684342210}]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.PayloadMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(PayloadMethodArgumentResolver.java:151)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.AmqpMessageHandlerMethodFactory$OptionalEmptyAwarePayloadArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AmqpMessageHandlerMethodFactory.java:99)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:118)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:147)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:115)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:278)
    ... 17 more`

In the end I want listeners to accept my custom classes not Strings. For now listener which expects String works fine, but the one which expects my Custom class (UserMessage) results in exception.
